# What is a "Process Canary"

Tags: terminology

In the book "Hard Code" by Eric Brechner, he states,

> Lying is one of a handful of valuable process canaries that can warn
>   you of trouble.

I've heard a dev or two toss around the old "canary".  What is it?

[Google didn't answer it for me.  Perhaps my keywords were a poor choice.]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Canaries were once used in [coal mines](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-does-it-mean-to-be-a-canary-in-a-coal-mine.htm) to find out if any poisonous gasses were around (the canary would die - the miners would get out). It was much safer than an open flame.

One assumes in this context that if there is much lying, the process is poisonous.

Comment: *Foo* Canaries is a term you'll see often if you hang around secure code types. See also, [Stack Canaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow#Stack_canaries)

Answer (score 19):

It just means a red flag, referring to the use of a [canary in coal mine](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/canary_in_a_coal_mine).

> ...caged canaries (birds) that mining workers would carry down into the mine tunnels with them. If dangerous gases such as methane or carbon monoxide leaked into the mine, the gases would kill the canary before killing the miners, thus providing a warning to exit the tunnels immediately...